# Extract html img tag in a string in c#

Tags: regex, string, c#-4.0

I have a html code as a string. I need to remove the img tag in that which has a particular src attribute.

e.g. `<img style="WIDTH:439px;" src="http://test/a.png">`

Say I need to find img tags which has "test" src attribute and remove the entire img tag from the string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regex is not the best way to go about this... Use a html parser.

Comment: What about Html agility pack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<img\s(?=.*?\btest\b)[^>]*>
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/31